# How to list directories in cloud storage from firebase admin sdk

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

How can I list all directories in my buckets **root** or **subdirectory** using the firebase admin nodejs sdk?

I have tried using `getFiles` but it only lists files and no directories.

```js
await bucket("backups").getFiles().then(([files]) => {
    files.forEach(file => console.log(file.name));  // Lists only files
});
```

Analyzing firebase backoffice XHR requests I found they are using following params to list files/directories:

```
prefix: 
internal_legacy: true
delimiter: /
pageToken: ...
maxResults: 100
```

But when using the "same" config for `getFiles` it lists nothing

```js
await bucket("backups").getFiles({prefix: "", delimiter: "/"}).then(([files]) => {
    files.forEach(file => console.log(file.name));  // Empty
});
```

Comment: Bear in mind that Cloud Storage is not a filesystem. Google Cloud console and gsutil provide the illusion of a [hierarchical file tree](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders#overview)

Comment: but this is not the case

Comment: @AndieVanille But the webui is able to list directories too so there must be a possibility. I guess I have to mimic the network traffic from the web ui.